# AndroidStudio - release build fails with "java.exe... Create process error=206...name or extension too long"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Suddenly I can't make a release of my app anymore, although I can build and launch it successfully.

I get following exception:

> Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'D:\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe''

And if I add following cmd options `--stacktrace --debug` I get an additional information:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe" (in directory "M:\dev\apps\app_name\app"): CreateProcess error=206, Der Dateiname oder die Erweiterung ist zu lang

"Der Dateiname oder die Erweiterung ist zu lang" means "name or extension is too long"

**Setup**

- my project lies underneath `M:\dev\apps\app_name`
- all my own libraries lie underneath `M:\dev\libraries`
- all my build tmp files lie underneath `M:\tmp\app_name`

So all paths are quite short...

**Assumption**

Somewhere a path is too long (on windows this means it's longer than 260 characters)

**What I did**

I ran following powershell cmd in all directories

```
cmd /c dir /s /b |? {$_.length -gt 260}
```

Not a single path is longer than 260...

**Question**

What else can I do here? Any ideas?

**EDIT**

It can't be the paths length. I sync my projects between two laptops which have the exact same folder structure. On my home laptop everything works... No idea why it is not working on my work laptop anymore...

Comment: Does one of your package names contain any special characters, like Ö in German?

Comment: Try it on different OS like mac or Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Try enabling multiDex in your project. It seems you are releasing this app first time or you have added more dependancies in your project

Comment: No, no special characters in any path... MultiDex is enabled and the app is released around once in month and it always worked... Small bug fixes are done, maybe dependencies update, nothing more...

Comment: getting the same error, did you found any solution?

Comment: have you resolved the issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I added an answer that may help some people in some cases...

Answer (score 0):

This did not help me but it may help others where the problem is something else than it was for me:

Inside *C:\Users<USERNAME>.gradle* (or wherever you have installed gradle) you can find the *init.gradle* file. Open this file and enter following content (or a similar one):

```
allprojects {
    buildDir = "M:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
}
```

This will have the effect that all projects intermediate and output files will be located nearly at a root path, namely *M:/tmp/project1/...*. This makes sure that you save a few characters in the temp folders where all the intermediate and output files will be generated in.